# Pagin With Ajax, Post no working

Tags: php, ajax

I Use this code for paging

```
function changePagination(pageId,liId,modul,userid){
 $(".flash").show();
 var dataModul = 'modul='+modul;
 var dataUser = 'userid='+userid;
 var dataString = 'pageId='+ pageId;
 $.ajax({
       type: "POST",
       url: "loadDataVerifikasi.php",
       data: dataString,
       data: dataModul,
       data: dataUser,
       cache: false,
       success: function(result){
             $(".flash").hide();
             $(".link a").removeClass("In-active current") ;
             $("#"+liId+" a").addClass( "In-active current" );
             $("#pageData").html(result);
       }
  });}
```

And this for an action file with name loadDataVerifikasi.php

```
if(isset($_POST['pageId']) && !empty($_POST['pageId'])){
  $id=$_POST['pageId'];
}
else{
  $id='0';
}
$pageLimit=PAGE_PER_NO*$id;
$query="select * from pengajuan_".$_POST['modul']." join verifikasi on      pengajuan_".$_POST['modul'].".ketkdpengajuan = verifikasi.ketkdpengajuan where kdadmin = '".$_POST['userid']."' group by kdverifikasi limit $pageLimit,".PAGE_PER_NO;
```

But $_POST['modul'] post nothing,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not familiar with your syntax.

Please try:

```
function changePagination(pageId,liId,modul,userid){
$(".flash").show();
 var datastring = {
     modul: modul,
     userid: userid,
     pageId: pageId 
 }
 $.ajax({
       type: "POST",
       url: "loadDataVerifikasi.php",
       data: dataString,
       cache: false,
       success: function(result){
             $(".flash").hide();
             $(".link a").removeClass("In-active current") ;
             $("#"+liId+" a").addClass( "In-active current" );
             $("#pageData").html(result);
       }
 });
}
```

The $.ajax `data` attribute accepts an object with key-value pairs

Answer (score 0):

I believe it is because you overwrite the data with dataUser.
I haven't tested i but the code below should work.
Also check out [this](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/) for more info

```
function changePagination(pageId,liId,modul,userid){
 $(".flash").show();
 var dataModul = 'modul='+modul;
 var dataUser = 'userid='+userid;
 var dataString = 'pageId='+ pageId;
 $.ajax({
       type: "POST",
       url: "loadDataVerifikasi.php",
       data: { 'dataString':dataString, 'dataModul':dataModul, 'dataUser':dataUser },          
       cache: false,
       success: function(result){
             $(".flash").hide();
             $(".link a").removeClass("In-active current") ;
             $("#"+liId+" a").addClass( "In-active current" );
             $("#pageData").html(result);
```

Comment: You changed the post names so the receiving php script would need to be changed in order to work with this code. Other than that same as my answer, the syntax of the $.ajax method in the question was off.

Comment: mm, i have tried the code, but still not working. any ?